autodesk platform services Oath V1 to V2 conversion of an existing code
I started learning autodesk platform services for iot with this tutorial at github.
GitHub - autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo: APS DataViz Extensions Demo:Visualizing IoT sensor data.
can you please explain me what changes should i make in code to make it migrate from Oath V1 to V2?
Right now its giving me error in compiling.
Thanks and Regards
A Young Developer
youtube and google search but could not find a proper tutorial
